# Increasing space size between table cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin

I have made a UITableViewController, and in it, have programmatically added in cells. I have used snippet code directly off of Microsoft's website on how to create a table using Xamarin: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/tables/populating-a-table-with-data

The only problem is that the code used produces a table which, when you add cells to, creates a spacer between each subsequent cell, of increasing size:

[image: Table Problem]

And my storyboard of the UITableViewController looks normal, and it contains no constraints or spacing:

[image: Storyboard of the table view]

Does anyone have any idea as to why this error might be occurring?

To clarify the code used for the source file for the table is:

```
public class mailSource : UITableViewSource
{
    string[] TableItems;
    string CellIdentifier = "TableCell";

    public mailSource(string[] items)
    {
        TableItems = items;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return TableItems.Length;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier);
        string item = TableItems[indexPath.Row];

        if (cell == null)
        { cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIdentifier); }

        cell.TextLabel.Text = item;

        return cell;
    }
}
```

And the code for the view controller is:

```
public partial class mailTableController : UITableViewController
{
    public mailTableController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        table = new UITableView(View.Bounds); // defaults to Plain style
        string[] tableItems = new string[] { "Vegetables", "Fruits", "Flower Buds", "Legumes", "Bulbs", "Tubers", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a" };
        table.Source = new mailSource(tableItems);
        Add(table);
    }
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear .

Comment: @vivekDas It feels quite clear that there is a space in-between each cell for no reason, and I want to get rid of the space, despite never programming a space to exist.

Comment: Select the tableview and then select the attribute inspector in the right panel then set the Separator as none, by default it will be 'Default'

Comment: @vivekDas Thank you for you quick and accurate response. Can you explain to me why spacing it as "default" creates the second line and the extra spacing?

Comment: See UITableview by default provide lines between cells. So its creates second line and do its own calculation to show the line, In your case I think your cell also having some separator line that is why it happening like that.